# Is it possible to update trigger table in update trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an update trigger for a table. When I am updating the table rows I need to check certain condition in trigger then based on that I want to update another column.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the documentation for [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), especially the remarks section, which includes:

> If an INSTEAD OF trigger defined on a table executes a statement against the table that would ordinarily fire the INSTEAD OF trigger again, the trigger is not called recursively. Instead, the statement is processed as if the table had no INSTEAD OF trigger and starts the chain of constraint operations and AFTER trigger executions.

If this, or other parts of the remarks section, don't answer your questions, you probably need to add more to your question about what problems you're having, or what issues you're concerned about.